# Android : Device density is returned as zero in old devices

Tags: android

Device density seems to return 0 in some devices. Am using the code below to calculate device density:

```
    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    wm.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    density = metrics.density;
```

This has resulted in some crashes in PlayStore. The users' devices mostly seem to be using Android version 2.2.x in such cases. How should we handle device density in these older devices?
Please help.

Answer (score 1):

If you are targeting API Levels earlier than 4. The metrics.density property is a floating point scaling factor from the reference density (160dpi). The same value now provided by metrics.densityDpi can be calculated

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
int densityDpi = (int)(metrics.density * 160f);
```

Comment: if metrics.density is returned as 0, then the value of the variable 'densityDpi' is also 0, right? But this was the issue I was facing.